# Laravel Condition Query Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

My Requirements : I select baseleads table with Random Order using following conditions

1. beaseleads currentstatus column value have **New Lead** Status or
2. beaseleads currentstatus column value have **Call Not Picking** status and **updated_at** date is **not Equal to Today Date**.

My Laravel Query is below

```
$baseleadsData=Baseleads::inRandomOrder()->Where('process_status',0)->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('current_status','New Lead');
        $query->Orwhere('current_status','Call Not Picking');
$query->OrwhereDate('updated_at', '!=', date('Y-m-d'));
    })->first();
```

Its not Working Properly. What is my Mistake.

Comment: try enable query logging. Do you get any error or don't you get the expected result?

Comment: I don't got expected result? @BasheerAhmedKharoti

Comment: Try `DB::enableQueryLog()` just before the query and after query put `dd(DB::getQueryLog())`

Comment: Also do post the desire `SQL` query so we can help with..

Answer (score 1):

```
->where(function ($query) {

        $query->where('current_status','New Lead')

              ->orWhere('current_status','Call Not Picking')

              ->orWhere('updated_at', '!=', date('Y-m-d').' 00:00:00');})->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I used Laravel, but have you tried

```
  $query->where('current_status', '=', 'New Lead');
        $query->Orwhere('current_status', '=', 'Call Not Picking');
```

instead of

```
  $query->where('current_status','New Lead');
        $query->Orwhere('current_status','Call Not Picking');
```

I'm not sure this will work as it looks like Laravel automatically makes the comparison. What is the error code youre getting? (You can turn debug mode on in your settings file)

Comment: if current status is equal to "Call Not Picking" status i need to check if updated_at is not equal to today date @Liam S

Comment: Sure, you'd just keep the next line. You could always keep it neat and use:
 $query->Orwhere([
['current_status', '=', 'Call Not Picking'],
['updated_at', '!=', date('Y-m-d')]
]);

Answer (score 0):

you need to use method names in **camelCase**
use `orWhere` and `orWhereDate`

Answer (score 0):

You did mistake of method name, use **Orwhere** to **orWhere**, **OrwhereDate** to **orWhereDate** and **Where** to **where**. and **orWhereDate** outside of **where query**.

```
$baseleadsData=Baseleads::inRandomOrder()
    ->where('process_status',0)
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('current_status','New Lead');
        $query->orWhere('current_status','Call Not Picking');
    })
    ->orWhereDate('updated_at', '!=', date('Y-m-d'))
    ->first();
```